# Apple Developer Fairplay Streaming Certificate Expiry

Tags: ios, certificate, drm, fairplay

The list of certificates on the Apple Developer web console shows the expiry of my Fairplay Streaming certificate as 'Never'. However, if I download the same certificate and import it into my KeyChain, the certificate details show the listed expiry as 29 July 2019. Which of these is correct? If the expiry in the certificate is correct, how do I renew it safely?

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of this writing, the expiration date in the certificate is not examined by the fairplay system during playback.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116308